# Concatenate Formula (Getting a #REF Error)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Afternoon all :)

This is kind of a little difficult to explain but ill happily clarify where ever it is needed. Thank you for taking the time to read this post ^^ Here goes..

I am currently creating a spreadsheet that is been extracted from the database whereby I am tasked to concatenate data from 2 adjacent cells. I change the database on a frequent basis adding or removing data wherever necessary so the range of data is always different. To concatenate the two cells I use the following formula:

e.g:  =IF(ISBLANK(B8&H8),"",B8&H8)

This formula works out great when im dealing with increasing amounts of data as I can simply drag the formula down as far as i want and i know that it will pick up the formula whenever I refresh the database without the need of seeing value errors when the formula ends up referring to a blank cell. The snag here (and my query as well) is if I have less data then before the formula within the last set of cells looks something like this:

e.g:  =IF(ISBLANK(#REF!&#REF!),"",#REF!&#REF!)

I have dealt with #REF before in other spreadsheets whereby I simply used a ISERROR in the statement but I dont know if there is a possible way of including this within my formula. I need the ISBLANK there so I have more control and dont have to drag the formula as often.

If there is a better way around this or a way to amend the current formula Id appreciate the help :)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your formula in an `IFERROR` function (e.g. `=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B8&H8),"",B8&H8), "")`? Sorry if I'm overlooking something :)

Comment: I agree with RocketDonkey, but here's an alternative, just so you don't have to repeat the true and false parts. `=IF(OR(ISERROR(B8&H8),ISBLANK(B8&H8)),"",B8&H8)`

Comment: `ISBLANK(B8 & H8)` will always return FALSE, even when the cells are empty.  Are you sure this formula does what you expect? `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B8),ISBLANK(H8)),"", B8 & H8)` might be what you need.

Comment: How are you currently getting the updated data into the spreadsheet?  Is this a copy and paste from another application?  Or is there a data connection embedded in the Excel workbook?

Comment: Hi all thank you for the feedback :) the formula provided by Daniel seemed to have worked in hiding the errors which will do for now but stepan is right in saying that its not resolving the issue with the formula (which is my next task to amend and a completely different topic to this post ^^), the clear helps but only when the data is there beforehand, and seems useless when i refresh the spreadsheet when less data is recieved and still get the error, I think this is unavoidable so ill need to alter my formula or add a macro. I am getting my external data using ODBC from a company database

Answer (score 2):

The only way you are going to get something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(#REF!&#REF!),"",#REF!&#REF!)
```

in the formula bar is if you(or the system you are using) are somehow deleting the cells that were originally referenced. This should be avoidable. You can *clear* the cells referenced instead of deleting them completely - then you won't get this error - and your formulas will remain intact. Now you can certainly use the formulas provided in the comments to hide the errors - but the root of your problem seems to me to be that the errors are occuring in the first place. Good Luck.